# how to specifically define table name in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

i have a DB which has a table named LIKE.

uppon trying to execute any query on the table, it gives me an error and i know it's because of the name which is trying to use the query keyword LIKE.

Now, i have "bypassed" this issue in MySQL by just selecting the table as

```
SELECT tk_oseba_id, COUNT(tk_tip_like_id) AS St_Like_haha
    FROM student999.`like`;
```

Now this same line wont work at `l...is there any special way to to this in oracle or how can i manipulate with the table by not using the LIKE keyword.

Comment: oracle wrap in quotes.`from student9999."like"` and it's case sensitive when you use the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Oracles's counter part to mysql's back tick is quote for defining tablenames/columns.

To use a key word as a table name though I recommend against it...

wrap the table name in quotes. `From student9999."like"`

AND... it forces case sensitivity when you use the quotes!

Comment: its a university db, so can help it if they make the names up.. i am also against it :) thanks

Comment: Why is that university teachers are so determined to teach their students bad practices?

Comment: Maybe so if the students encounter this situation in the real world the student know how to handle it. Can't tell you how many times I ran into a table called `order` when supporting ERPs for small business; or even on SO.